# Find if current time is multiple of a time window from a fixed baseline

Tags: c#, datetime, time

Assume an Event starts at 9:15AM and I need to check something after every 4-Mins (9:19AM/9:23Am and on so) but however I may start my check-process at any time of the day (Need not be exactly aligned to that 4-Min Time Window of Polling), say for example 10:11AM or any arbitrary time (Not aligned to 4-Min + Baseline Time). I however want to ensure that whenever I start my check-process, it should be aligned (it should only check 9:19Am/9:23Am/9:9:27Am and so on checkpoints even if I start at say 9:11Am. if I start at 9:11Am, it should not consider 9:11Am + 4-Mins but wait till it reaches the checkpoint 9:19AM and so on)

This is what I have done so far in C# but it is not working and condition never satisfies.

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(9, 15, 0);
/*A Test Thread Function for Unit Testing the Logic*/
public void MyMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if (start <= now)
        {
            double difference = now.Minutes - start.Minutes;
            if (difference % Convert.ToInt32(4) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waitin for Tick Collection time to start at a Time Window which is a Multiple of " + 4);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Required Tick Elapsed " + trade_Entry_candle_length);
                return;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Actually I would be receiving TICKS from Stock Exchange and whenever I start my AutoBot, I want AutoBot to start accepting the Ticks only when Current "NOW" Time is aligned to that Interval of 4-Mins (Irrespective of when I start), Once I am aligned once then I can keep on creating the 4-Min Window.

Comment: Can't you use a Timer?

Comment: As Jimi mentioned, you could use a Timer and schedule the timer to elapse in the 4 minute tick you want. Then, when you get the tick, schedule again for the next 4 minute tick. Ad infinitum.

Comment: Actually I would be receiving TICKS from Stock Exchange and whenever I start my AutoBot, I want AutoBot to start accepting the Ticks only when Current "NOW" Time is aligned to that Interval of 4-Mins (Irrespective of when I start), Once I am aligned once then I can keep on creating the 4-Min Window.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next time to "do something" using code like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    int interval = 4;
    TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(9, 15, 0); // 9:15 am
    DateTime nextCheck = getNextCheckTime(startTime, interval);
    Console.WriteLine("nextCheck = " + nextCheck.ToString());
}

public DateTime getNextCheckTime(TimeSpan startTime, int intervalInMinutes)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(startTime);
    while (DateTime.Now > dt)
    {
        dt = dt.AddMinutes(intervalInMinutes);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

You can use a Timer, as others have suggested, to see if the current time is past the "next check" time retrieved from the function.  Once that occurs, you can do something and then get the next check time again.